# "Yichud L'Olam" in Hilchos Muktzeh

Tags: halacha, shabbat, time, muktzeh

In Hilchos Muktzeh we find there is an idea that even a rock ("evan") one can be m'yached (set aside) for a certain purpose allowing one to move it around on Shabbos (See SA OC Siman 308 Sif 22.) However in such a case one needs "yichud l'olam". That it was set aside for ever that one will use this rock for that purpose. Does "l'olam" mean mamash "l'olam" (forever.) Or would it even work if someone set it aside for a particular purpose for a years time (for example.)